# Problems with two-way binding treeviewitem.isExpanded with hierarchical data template

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I attempted to bind the isExpanded property of the TreeViewItems to a property of the view-model. Unfortunatly it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the setup:

The **Tree**:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0">
     <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
             <Setter Property="IsExpanded"  Value="{Binding Expanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
         </Style>
     </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

DataContext is set from code behind.

The **Hierarchichal data template**:

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:StructuredViewNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <!-- content omitted -->    
 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

**Node**:

```
public class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // Rest of node omitted

    #region Expanded
    private bool _isExpanded;
    public bool Expanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            throw new Exception("Set to: " + value);
            _isExpanded = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged("Expanded");
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And finally **StructuredViewNode**:

```
public class StructuredViewNode : Node
{
    //content omitted
}
```

I would exspect an exception to be trown when I expand a node, but the property does not seem to get set in the viewmodel, do you know why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue with a treeview, but it worked for me and raised the error as I expand a node.
Either you're eating that error somehow or you have something different in your version - in code you've not posted.
My markup is similar, I bind Families to the itemssource of the treeview and have exactly the same itemcontainerstyle.

My code:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Family> Families { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    { 

    Families = new ObservableCollection<Family>();

    Family family1 = new Family() { Name = "The Doe's" };
    family1.Members.Add(new FamilyMember() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42 });
                    family1.Members.Add(new FamilyMember() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39 });
                    family1.Members.Add(new FamilyMember() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13 });
                    Families.Add(family1);

                    Family family2 = new Family() { Name = "The Moe's" };
    family2.Members.Add(new FamilyMember() { Name = "Mark Moe", Age = 31 });
                    family2.Members.Add(new FamilyMember() { Name = "Norma Moe", Age = 28 });
                    Families.Add(family2);
    }
}
public class Family :baseVM
{
    public Family()
    {
        this.Members = new ObservableCollection<FamilyMember>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FamilyMember> Members { get; set; }
    private bool _isExpanded;
    public bool Expanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            throw new Exception("Set to: " + value);
            _isExpanded = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Expanded");
        }
    }

}

public class FamilyMember : baseVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    private bool _isExpanded;
    public bool Expanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            throw new Exception("Set to: " + value);
            _isExpanded = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Expanded");
        }
    }

}
public class baseVM
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to get a better minimum working example of what is going wrong. Its good to know that the error is not in this part at least.

Comment: Ok, I stepped through the procedure by attaching the visual studio debugger to the tool that contains my wpf... and you were right, I'm eating the exception. You shouldn't program sick I guess^^ 
Thanks a lot!